# Побитовый сдвиг <<, не получается операция

Tags: битовые-операции

Двоичная система исчисления.

Знаковый оператор сдвига вправо >>

" Все биты смещаются вправо. Число слева дополняется нулем, если число положительное и единицей, если отрицательное. Операция используется для быстрого деления на 2. Если делится нечетное число, то остаток отбрасывается для положительных чисел и сохраняется для отрицательных.

"Знаковый оператор сдвига влево <<

Все биты смещаются влево. Число справа дополняется нулем. Операция используется для быстрого умножения на 2. Если оператор применяется к числу, умножение на 2 которого будет больше максимального значения int (2147483647), то в результате будет отрицательное число. Это происходит потому, что краний левый бит, который отвечает за знак числа, выставляется в единицу, что соответствует отрицательным числам.

Почему когда я делаю все в еклипс, то там работает не так? Например:

```
    int x = 10;
    String str = Integer.toBinaryString(x);

    System.out.println(x+ "  "+ str );  //10  1010

     x = x <<2;
     System.out.println(x);  // 40
```

Тут же другое должно получится???

Это как основной вопрос.

Второй вопрос: как число

```
String str = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
```

уже разложеное побитно, записать в инт, чтобы сделать с ним побитовую операцию?

Comment: Вы взяли 10, сдвинули дважды влево (то есть дважды умножили на 2, то есть на 4) и получили 40. Все ок. Что Вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: я ожидал увидеть, что 10 в двоичной системе будет 1010, если я на 2 позиции сдвигаю влево, то убирается первые 10 и в конец дополняются 00, то есть будет 1000 в двоичной системе, так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не так. 1010 сдвигается на 2 разряда влево и получаем 101000, что соответствует числу 40.

Отвечая на второй вопрос: `Integer.parseUnsignedInt(str, 2)`

Comment: подскажите, почему этого метода нет в классе Integer?

Answer (score 4):

[[@kamenb](/users/31686/kamenb)](/users/31686/kamenb), в двоичной системе вообще-то будет

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010
```

, и то если система 32битная. Со сдвигом -

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 1000
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтоб запись полная была? А то Integer.toBinaryString(x)  ----  00 постоянно откидывает?

Comment: @kamenb

> а как сделать так что б запись полная была?

докинуть слева нулей до длины Integer на текущей платформе (Integer.SIZE).

> откидует

откид**ывае**т